# Вывод в реальном времени результатов запросов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который раз в определенное время должен делать запрос к скрипту и возвращать данные и так 20 раз. Но проблема в том, что по нажатию на кнопку он ждет 20 секунд, пока закончится весь цикл, а потом уже выводит все результаты работы, а мне необходимо, чтобы он выводил данные в реальном времени, скрипт вернул ответ, отобразил, подождал определенное время и снова выполнился и отобразил ответ. `SetInterval` использовать не могу, потому что задержка будет зависить от того, какое значение вернет скрипт, оно будет постоянно меняться. Как можно реализовать отображение данных в реальном времени? Все должно быть последовательно, выполняться должен один запрос, функции же, которые я видел, выполняют их параллельно.

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

function SendParams(i) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "get",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $('p').append(i + ' ' + data + '<br>');
    }
  });
}

$("button").click(function() {
  var j;
  for (j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
    SendParams(j);
    sleep(1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В success метод setTimeout на 20 секунд сделать с функцией, телом которого является ваша логика отображения + запуск нового запроса.

```js
var j = 1;

function sendParams() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "get",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $('p').append(j + ' ' + data + '<br>');
      if (j > 21) {return;}
      j++;
      // data.time - время которое приходит в ответе от которого вы зависите
      setTimeout(function(){ sendParams();}, data.time); 
    }
  });
}

$("button").click(function() {
    sendParams();
  }
});
```

Примерно так, если я вас правильно понял

Comment: Именно то, что нужно, спасибо